# Peut-on dire : « apprendre sur le travail en équipe » ?

Tags: prépositions

J'hésite sur l'emploi du mot "sur".

En plus la phrase complète est : "j'ai l'expérience dans le sport, ce qui m'appris sur le travail en équipe, qui est une qualité nécessaire pour ma profession". À mon avis, il y a une abondance des "qui". Sinon, est-il correct de l'écrire dans une lettre formelle?

Answer (score 3):

Vous dites "j'ai l'expérience dans le sport" il faudra dire "j'ai de l'expérience dans le sport". Mais cette expression donne une idée très vague de votre expérience: En tant que sportif ou professionnel du sport. De plus, "avoir de l’expérience" veut dire que ça peut être négligeable ou être en contact de la chose pas plus.
Il serait préférable de donner une appréciation quant à votre expérience professionnelle au niveau du sport. Pour le dire ainsi:

1. Si vous êtes professionnel du sport:
   **J'ai une expérience professionnelle du travail en équipe au niveau sportif.**
2. Si vous êtes sportif professionnel:
   **J'ai une expérience de premier plan du travail en équipe étant un sportif professionnel.**

Ces deux formulations vous évitent d'utiliser "une qualité nécessaire pour ma profession" car étant un professionnel soit sportif ou du sport il est clair que le travail d'équipe est une notion de base pour vous. Ceci dit, vous devrez donner plus de détails concernant votre expérience par la suite. Ou juste survoler l'idée et proposer un contact direct pour donner plus de détails à ce sujet.

Mais là en relisant tout ça, je me dis que ce serait mieux d'éviter cette notion si vous ne pouvez pas expliquer plus en détail ce que vous voulez dire.

Ci-dessous, vous trouverez certaines notions avec quelques différences sémantiques qui donnent une idée sur le fait de juste travailler ensemble, travailler ensemble en divisant les tâches ou en collaborant ou faire tous ça en allant vers un seul but.

- **Travail en équipe**: concernant l'organisation du travail; chacun de son coté; possibilité de redondance des efforts
- **Travail d'équipe**: concernant la méthodologie de travail; chacun de son coté; élimination des redondances
- **Travail collectif**: concernant la méthodologie de travail; Tous ensemble vers le même but, possibilité de redondance

ou carrément

- **Travail de groupe/collaboratif**: concernant la méthodologie et organisation de travail; collaboration vers le même but en éliminant les redondances. Car c'est le groupe qui travaille et non l'individu.

IMHO, je sais que les gens font juste la différence entre sport collectif, sports de groupe et sports individuels. Mais, je pense qu'il y a une différentiation à faire entre les différents types de sport collectifs.

Answer (score 2):

On n'a pas une expérience *sur*, mais une expérience *de* :

> J'ai l'expérience du sport collectif qui m'a appris le travail d'équipe, [ce qui est une] qualité nécessaire à ma profession.
>
> J'ai l'expérience du sport collectif, cela m'a appris le travail d'équipe, [] qualité nécessaire à ma profession.
>
> On peut aussi écrire : j'ai *pratiqué le sport collectif*, si le mot *expérience* figure ailleurs dans la page.

Il y plusieurs façons de supprimer les lourdeurs de langage qui sont à éviter dans les courriers formels :

- ne pas les écrire lorsqu'elles sont répétitives et que la phrase suivante est une induction de la précédente (on peut supprimer les mots entre [ ] du premier exemple),
- changer le mot relatif *qui*  en *cela* (si l'on veut vraiment insister, remplacer [ ]  par *ce qui est une* du deuxième exemple),
- réorganiser la phrase en se servant de la contraction de texte qui élimine les notions redondantes :

> Le sport collectif m'a appris le travail d'équipe, expérience nécessaire à ma profession.

N.B. J'ai ajouté *collectif* pour la cohésion de la phrase, les sports individuels exigent souvent des qualités opposées à celles que souhaitez mettre en valeur.